# What is the appropriate way of updating nested resources using HTTP PUT?

Tags: rest, webapi, http-put

I and my colleague are discussing how HTTP PUT requests with nested resources should be correctly implemented.

Example situation: Each user can have multiple addresses, which can be updated, deleted or added. We are trying to minimize the surface of our API as well as perform most of the operations within a single transaction, therefore a single PUT endpoint should ideally handle all those operations.

Developer 1 suggests this approach:
**PUT /users/1**

```
{
  "fullName": "John Doe",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "street": "street1",
      "zipCode": "15000"
    },
    {
      "street": "street2",
      "zipCode": "15200"
    }
  ]
}
```

In this example, all the user's existing addresses that are currently in DB will be deleted and replaced by these two provided addresses - "street1" and "street2". In case the provided value for the addresses property is an empty array such as `"addresses:" : []` - all user's addresses would be deleted from DB. Also, it would be prohibited to set addresses to null: `"addresses":null`, only empty array or an array with items can be provided.

Developer 2 suggests this approach:
**PUT /users/1**

```
{
  "fullName": "John Doe",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "street": "street1",
      "zipCode": "15000"
    },
    {
      "street": "street2",
      "zipCode": "15200"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note - there is `"id":5` in the first address object. In this example, an address with id 5 was provided - this would result in an update of an existing address with Id 5. Moreover, there is also an address without Id specified. This would create a new user's address (I mean a new address record with a new Id in the database). Finally, all currently existing user's addresses (excluding address with id=5) will be deleted from the database. To sum it up, this approach allows the frontend developers to specify, whether an existing entity should be updated, or whether a new address with a new Id should be created.

Honestly, I have no idea whether a client application should be in charge of specifying whether the address should be updated or created. The first example always re-creates the user's address.

In case the address had also an uploaded file, it would be possible (using example 2) to keep that uploaded file in the database and update only the zipCode - the example from the developer 1 does not allow for this - a new address is always created, so any previously uploaded files linked to that address would be also "cascade" deleted.

We could also alternatively use HTTP DELETE or HTTP PATCH endpoints to delete or modify the user's addresses, but as stated earlier, we are trying to have as few endpoints as possible and use a single transaction to perform most of the db-related operations.

I would like to know your opinions on whether nested resources should be identified with IDs and whether the two presented approaches are good enough or on the other hand, fundamentally flawed / violating some REST API standards.

Comment: The second example is IMHO not understandable. If you want to create only one rest endpoint you have to add commands on JSON level. Nobody enforces that the JSON structure is pure data. Allow it to contain multiple commands with each an JSON structure e.g.to be added or updated.

Comment: Thank you @Robert, this appears to be an interesting approach.
{
  "fullName": "John Doe",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "street": "street1",
      "zipCode": "15000",
      "command":"update"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "street": "street2",
      "zipCode": "15200",
      "command" : "delete"
    },
    {      
      // no need to specify ID here
      "street": "street3",
      "zipCode": "15300",
      "command" : "add"
    }
    // other user's already existing addresses in DB are left intact
  ]
}